# string format, text containing quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok say I have some text like so:

Hello 5'f @ "USA"

im reading the text in my controller & Model as follows

```
Notes =  string.Format(@"{0}", client.Notes)
```

I am then displaying it on my page as follows:

```
 <input type="text"  value="@Model.Notes">
```

Then looking at what the browser\complied text is

```
<input type="text"  value=" Hello 5&#39;f @ &quot;USA&quot>
```

which is throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

What do I need to do to format it correctly?

Comment: Hmm it's like the Razor engine is getting confused with the double quote at the end of the string - can you try `value='@Model.Notes'` (single quotes)

Comment: yeap tried that as well with no luck

Comment: What version of MVC? If you remove the end double quote does it work? (FYI it's generally best to state the exact technology you are using in the tags).

Comment: use from @html.Raw(Model.Notes)

Comment: Did you have `Hello 5&#39;f @ &quot;USA&quot` in your Model.Notes?

Comment: Please provide a short, but complete, reproducible example of the problem because as far as I am concerned - [this works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SEm4XU).

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notes)` in your view? This should resolve all encoding issues.

Comment: What difference does `TextBoxFor` make? That's just a helper method for binding the UI to a property.

Comment: @James, This helper is designed to avoid facing problems with code `<input type="text"  value="@Model.Notes">` like this. It is not a proper way to build input for model property.

Comment: Yeah, precisely, it's a helper method to avoid you having to write the HTML yourself. It does nothing extra to HTML encode the output to what `@Model.Notes` already does.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This should encode the string for you.

That means:

```
Notes =  string.Format(@"{0}", HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(client.Notes));
```

Answer (score -2):

I think if you use from @html.Raw() your problem solve

```
<input type="text"  value="@Html.Raw(Model.Notes)">
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason why `Raw` will work or are you just guessing? Because using `Html.Raw` has [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) written all over it. Plus, `@Model.Notes` should work and is the recommended approach when outputting HTML encoded content.

Comment: @James "This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which renders unencoded HTML."MSDN

Comment: the point I am making, which I don't think you appear to get, is your solution to the problem is to avoid it completely (which also happens to be very dangerous).

Comment: @James To prevent XSS you must check user input then store it in database (a library  like AntiXSS can help you) if user input doesn't any dangeriuse script you can show it by @Html.Raw().is this idea wrong?

Comment: Preventing XSS has nothing to do with how you store data in the database but rather how you *render* it on the client - using `Html.Raw` renders content unencoded which opens you to XSS.